# Is there such a thing as a flashbulb case or a convenient way to carry and organize flashbulbs?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, manual-flash

Does anyone have any tips for transporting flashbulbs?  I want to carry a small selection without having to smash multiple cardboard boxes into my small bag or losing track of which is which.

Where there ever flashbulb cases?  I have a shop and I'm pretty handy so I could make something but a starting point would be nice.

I'm trying to transport M-series bulbs. (M2, M3, M5, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up ordering 1" nylon tube with a 7/8" ID on McMaster-Carr along with vinyl end caps.  Cut some discs from some left over closed cell foam.

This lets me stack them vertically in the tube with padding in between and capping the ends.

Very lightweight and fits in my bag easily.  7/8" is big enough for all the M-series bulbs I have.

Part numbers below if someone else runs into the same situation. (Yeah right.)

https://www.mcmaster.com/8628K67/

https://www.mcmaster.com/40005K35/

Update: I found that if I put them in the tube socket-to-socket then they can slide past each other a little and fit even more in the tube.  I've attached an illustration to demonstrate the orientation.[image]

Comment: I am not visualizing your solution. The links you posted do not work for me. Do not load.

Comment: I fixed the links and changed the wording.  I'm just stacking them on end in the tube and capping the ends.

Answer (score 2):

You can get plastic cases in many types of sizes and quality, from cheap [food storage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KKM0GC) tubs to more rugged pelican cases.

I would go with a [Pelican Case](https://www.pelican.com/us/en/product/cases/micro/1060),  and add some [Pick and Pluck foam](https://www.amazon.com/pick-pluck-foam/s?k=pick%20pluck%20foam) to it. They come in dozens of sizes. I bought a big one for all of my photo gear for my trip down the Colorado river in the grand canyon.

There are some  small Pelican cases that have a carabiner clip so you can clip it onto your camera bag so it is not taking up room in your bag.

You can cut the foam any way to fit any case, you can pluck out a recess for the base of the bulbs and put a solid foam piece on top to keep them from rattling and banging together.